# Filling a short time series for cross correlation

Tags: time-series, sampling, cross-correlation

I have two times series data **X** and **Y**. **X** is the number of times the phrase "sole proprietorship" is searched on a local search engine while **Y** is the number of sole proprietorship venture newly created. Both series are measured on a monthly frequency but in different time periods. To be specific, series **X** spans 2020-2021 (24 rows) while series **Y** spans 2016-2021 (65 rows). They have the same end time.

I intend to do a time-lagged cross correlation to understand the relationship between the two series. However, cross correlation requires that the two series are of the same length. So it's either I trim the **Y** series to fit **X** (which leads to substantial amount of information loss given that **X** is a short series already) or I find a way to fill **X** up to 65 rows such that my analysis is still plausible.

Now, given that I prefer the latter method (my research shows that doing stationary test and even cross correlation for short series comes with a lot of issues), I was able to get another time series data, say **Z**. **Z** is a Google trend data similar to **X** (that is, number of times the phrase "sole proprietorship" is searched) but covers the time period of **Y**. Left to my devices, I would just take from **Z** to fill **X** and move on, but the range of values for **X**(3700-18000) is far greater than that of **Z**(120-400).

So my question is

1. Is it even wise at all to fill **X** with **Z**?
2. And if it is okay, what method is most likely to produce more realistic values?

What I tried initially was a moving average method to fill the values but I feel there should be a more reliable method.

Also, the closest question I found is [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/211016/correlation-between-two-time-series-of-unequal-size) but the answer suggests resampling the frequency (which is not an issue in my case) and dynamic time warping, an approach I have tried but don't know how to clearly interpret.